# Creating Mex Files in Matlab with GFortran on Windows

Tags: matlab, fortran, gfortran, mex

I'm working on adding a Fortran routine into Matlab (via the Mex functions). I'm just trying to write a simple program to understand how the links are made between Matlab, Mex and Fortran.

I wrote a simple program which takes in a value of `x` and `y`, adds them together and outputs `z`. However, when I try to run in Matlab after compiling, Matlab simply crashes without explanation. Any idea what I've done wrong here?

```
! MEX FILE EXAMPLE
!


module yprime_mod ! test module for gnumex and g95
  use mexinterface
contains
  subroutine yprime(x, y, z) ! subroutine yprime(z, t, y, error, x)
    implicit none
    double precision :: x, y, z
    intent(in)  :: x, y
    intent(out) :: z
    ! 
    z=x+y;
  end subroutine yprime
end module yprime_mod

subroutine mexfunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)
  use yprime_mod
  implicit none
  integer :: nlhs, nrhs, plhs(nlhs), prhs(nrhs)
  double precision, pointer :: xp, yp, z
  !
  if (nrhs /= 2) call mexerrmsgtxt('yprime requires two input arguments')
  if (nlhs > 1) call mexerrmsgtxt('yprime requires one output argument')
  call c_f_pointer(mxgetpr(prhs(1)), xp)  ! assign pointers to parameters
  call c_f_pointer(mxgetpr(prhs(2)), yp)
  call c_f_pointer(mxgetpr(plhs(1)), z)
  call yprime(xp, yp, z)
end subroutine mexfunction
```

Comment: Is the default Integer kind big enough for the p*hs arguments?  Try declaring them as `mwPointer`s.  Also, if you're compiling this with the MEX Fortran API directly (no intervening C), I don't think you need `c_f_pointer`.

Comment: Can you see if the [basic example for Fortran source files](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/create-fortran-source-mex-file.html) works ?

Comment: Hi @Adam may I ask you how you were forcing matlab to use gfortran? I read that only (the very expensive) Intel's compilers are supported, and I'd also like to enforce Matlab to rely on gfortran instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing Fortran, I followed the basic example, and it's working.

I know nothing about using `c_f_pointer` (it might be related to the crash).
I think code most likely crashes because you forgot to call `plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mrows,ncols,0)` for creating matrix for the return argument.

Here is the modified code:

```
! MEX FILE EXAMPLE
!

#include "fintrf.h"

module yprime_mod ! test module for gnumex and g95
  !use mexinterface
contains
  subroutine yprime(x, y, z) ! subroutine yprime(z, t, y, error, x)
    implicit none
    double precision :: x, y, z
    intent(in)  :: x, y
    intent(out) :: z
    ! 
    z=x+y;
  end subroutine yprime
end module yprime_mod
!   
!    
subroutine mexfunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)
  use yprime_mod
  implicit none
  !integer :: nlhs, nrhs, plhs(nlhs), prhs(nrhs)
  !double precision, pointer :: xp, yp, zp
  !double precision x, y, z 

  !mexFunction arguments:
  mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
  integer nlhs, nrhs

  !Function declarations:
  mwPointer mxGetPr
  mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
  mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN

  !Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
  mwPointer xp, yp, zp

  !Arguments for computational routine:
  real*8 x, y, z

  if (nrhs /= 2) call mexerrmsgtxt('yprime requires two input arguments')
  if (nlhs > 1) call mexerrmsgtxt('yprime requires one output argument')

  !To points to the input matrices data, use the mxGetPr function.
  xp = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
  yp = mxGetPr(prhs(2))

  !Create Fortran arrays from the input arguments.
  call mxCopyPtrToReal8(xp,x,1)
  call mxCopyPtrToReal8(yp,y,1)

  !Create scalar for the return argument.
  plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)

  !Use the mxGetPr function to assign the y_ptr argument to plhs(1).
  zp = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

  !call c_f_pointer(mxgetpr(prhs(1)), xp)  ! assign pointers to parameters
  !call c_f_pointer(mxgetpr(prhs(2)), yp)
  !call c_f_pointer(mxgetpr(plhs(1)), z)

  !call yprime(xp, yp, zp)

  !Perform Calculation
  call yprime(x, y, z)

  !Copy Results to Output Argument
  call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(z,zp,1)

end subroutine mexfunction
```

I used Intel Compiler for compilation, and debugged the code (step by step) in Visual Studio.
The `mex` file is working correctly...

Comment: Hi Adam, can you please give some feedback regarding my answer?